# There is no result of my html file in any browser

Tags: html, browser

I have a 64bit system with windows10.

After I wrote an html file in notepad and saved it, the result shown in all browsers in my system are the same.

It's just the raw html code not the result that is supposed to be.
What should i do?

[image]

Comment: your file has txt extension. remove .txt and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not save your file as a HTML document, you saved it as TXT.

Open your explorer and show your file extensions.

[image]

Now rename your `sfss.htm.txt` into `sfss.html`

Answer (score -1):

Save Your html file with .html Extension and Then run it file. 
Like index.html